# fread errors with custom colClasses

Tags: r, data.table, fread

I'm trying to figure out how to fix the following issues.
Here is a code example:

```
fileName <- "data.csv"
colClasses <- sapply(read.csv(fileName, nrows=100),class)
colClasses["time"] = "POSIXct"
colClasses["userName"] = colClasses["clientHost"] = "character"
data <- fread(input = fileName, sep = ",", sep2 = NULL,
              colClasses = colClasses, nrows = 2, header=TRUE, drop=c(15,16))
```

The following error occurs:

`Error in fread(input = fileName, sep = ",", sep2 = NULL, nrows = 2, colClasses = colClasses,  : 
    Column name 'userName' in colClasses[[1]] not found`

I'm using the R 3.1.2 with data.tables package 1.9.4

The second issue is that when I don't specify the colClasses variable, then data is imported, but the header is equal to the the first row of the data, and not the names of the columns in the file.

Comment: can you add a sample of what's contained in data.csv ?

Comment: Try letting `header` default to `auto`, and kindly add some sample data (e.g. read in 10 rows with `read.csv` then print with `dput`).

Comment: Actually that was a bug in `data.table`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in data.table library, which had been fixed.

Comment: Fixed in what version?

Comment: It should be in 1.9.6, as indicated here: [link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1000)